# Why this multiline macro doesn't work?

Tags: c, macros

Doesn't look like it was parced correctly even. But it looks fine to me.

Maybe it doesn't like newlines? Tried without them.

Maybe it must be in UPPER CASE? I honestly have no idea.

Maybe it doesn't like ////comments?

```
#define fill(where_l, where_r, where_t, where_b, what_l, what_r, what_t, what_b) \
                                                                    \
    ////lt                                      \
    *p++ = where_l;                   \  
    *p++ = where_t;                   \
    *p++ = 0.5f;                    \
    *p++ = 1.0f;                   \
    *p++ = what_l;                   \
    *p++ = what_t;                   \
                                    \
    ////rt                   \
    *p++ = where_r;                   \
    *p++ = where_t;                   \
    *p++ = 0.5f;                   \
    *p++ = 1.0f;                   \
    *p++ = what_r;                   \
    *p++ = what_t;                   \
                   \
    ////lb                   \
    *p++ = where_l;                   \
    *p++ = where_b;                   \
    *p++ = 0.5f;                   \
    *p++ = 1.0f;                   \
    *p++ = what_l;                   \
    *p++ = what_b;                   \
                   \
    ////rb                   \
    *p++ = where_r;                   \
    *p++ = where_b;                   \
    *p++ = 0.5f;                   \
    *p++ = 1.0f;                   \
    *p++ = what_r;                   \
    *p++ = what_b;                   \
```

Errors:

```
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(569) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(569) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(570) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(570) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(570) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(569) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(571) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(571) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(571) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(569) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(572) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(572) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(572) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(569) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(573) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(573) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(573) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
```

Deleted comments completely, now errors are:

```
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(569) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(569) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(569) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(570) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(570) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(570) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(571) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(571) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(571) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(572) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(572) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(572) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(574) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(574) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(574) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(575) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(575) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(575) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(576) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(576) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(576) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(577) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(577) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(577) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(578) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(578) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(578) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(579) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(579) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(579) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(581) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(581) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(581) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(582) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(582) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(582) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(583) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(583) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(583) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(584) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(584) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(584) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(585) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(585) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(585) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(586) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(586) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(586) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(588) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(588) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(588) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(589) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(589) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(589) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(590) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(590) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(590) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(591) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(591) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(591) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(592) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(592) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(592) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(593) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(593) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(593) : error C2086: 'int *p' : redefinition
1>        c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(568) : see declaration of 'p'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(641) : error C2297: '*' : illegal, right operand has type 'float *'
1>c:\_src\directxsamples\ex_tut2_showjpg\tut2_vertices.cpp(641) : error C2017: illegal escape sequence
```

It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details.

Here is how I use it:

```
            float* p = (float*)malloc(999);
            fill(i_im_x, i_im_x + 512.0f,
                i_im_y, i_im_y + 512.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f);
```

Comment: Syntax highlighting in my ide is wrong for it.

Comment: You have a lot of commented "\" ... Try to use the comments using the syntax `/* comment */` where "comment" is whatever you want!

Comment: If ever there was a macro that should have been a function...

Comment: Replace all `////lt` to `/*lt*/` , macro will be okay

Comment: Maybe i will make it a function, thought I can't properly pass *p around. My compiler is most likely too dumb to inline it properly.

Comment: removed comments and empty lines, even more errors. Added to the post.

Comment: Please show how you use the `fill` macro, the problem may be _there_. Read this: [mcve]

Comment: added 10 more to go...

Comment: The macro ends with a `\\`, i.e., whatever comes next is part of the macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this:

1. Replace all `////xx` comments by `/* xx */`
2. Remove the stray space character after the `\` in following line:

---

```
*p++ = where_l;                   \ 
                                   ^ stray space here
```

---

This was not obvious because you cannot see that stray space unless you put the cursor there.

3. Remove the final `\` in the very last line of the macro:

---

```
 *p++ = what_b;                   \
                                  ^ remove this
```

---

**Working example:**

```
#define fill(where_l, where_r, where_t, where_b, what_l, what_r, what_t, what_b) \
                                                                    \
    /*lt*/                                      \
    *p++ = where_l;                   \
    *p++ = where_t;                   \
    *p++ = 0.5f;                    \
    *p++ = 1.0f;                   \
    *p++ = what_l;                   \
    *p++ = what_t;                   \
    \
    /* rt */                  \
    *p++ = where_r;                   \
    *p++ = where_t;                   \
    *p++ = 0.5f;                   \
    *p++ = 1.0f;                   \
    *p++ = what_r;                   \
    *p++ = what_t;                   \
                   \
    /*lb*/                   \
    *p++ = where_l;                   \
    *p++ = where_b;                   \
    *p++ = 0.5f;                   \
    *p++ = 1.0f;                   \
    *p++ = what_l;                   \
    *p++ = what_b;                   \
                   \
    /*rb*/                   \
    *p++ = where_r;                   \
    *p++ = where_b;                   \
    *p++ = 0.5f;                   \
    *p++ = 1.0f;                   \
    *p++ = what_r;                   \
    *p++ = what_b;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  float* p = (float*)malloc(999);
  fill(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
}
```

Comment: This helped greatly. Found the cause, there were spaces after `/`.